# Sagemaker create-processing-job with entrypoint ContainerArguments error

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-sagemaker

I'm running the following command in Sagemaker CLI:

```
aws sagemaker create-processing-job --processing-job-name serialize-test \
        --processing-resources 'ClusterConfig={InstanceCount=1,InstanceType="ml.m5.large",VolumeSizeInGB=5}' \
        --app-specification ImageUri="awsid.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/custom-container-name",ContainerEntrypoint=["python",$SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM],ContainerArguments=["--data","s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-awsid/data/003.wav"] \
        --role-arn arn:aws:iam::awsid:role/rolename \
        --processing-output-config 'Outputs=[{OutputName="output1",S3Output={S3Uri="s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-awsid/output/",LocalPath="/opt/ml/processing/output1/",S3UploadMode="Continuous"}}]'
```

The cloud logs show the following error message:

```
2024-02-23T15:38:40.881-05:00   unknown option --data
2024-02-23T15:38:40.881-05:00   usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
2024-02-23T15:38:40.881-05:00   Try `python -h' for more information.
```

The image I've imported is an extension of a pre-built one.  The Dockerfile looks like this

```
# SageMaker PyTorch image
FROM 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-inference:2.0.0-cpu-py310

ENV PATH="/opt/ml/code:${PATH}"

# this environment variable is used by the SageMaker PyTorch container to determine our user code directory.
ENV SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY /opt/ml/code

# /opt/ml and all subdirectories are utilized by SageMaker, use the /code subdirectory to store your user code.
COPY serialize.py /opt/ml/code/serialize.py

ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM serialize.py
```

I've ran the steps to save this Docker image successfully to the ECR.

Serialize.py:

```py
import argparse
import pickle
from sagemaker.serializers import DataSerializer


def main(args):
    data = args.data
    # Read the audio file
    with open(data, "rb") as f:
        audio_data = f.read()

    # Serialize the audio data
    serializer = DataSerializer(content_type='audio/wav')
    serialized_audio = serializer.serialize(audio_data)

    with open('output.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(serialized_audio, f)


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--data", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    main(args)
```

I understand that there's something wrong with my syntax for `--app-specification', specifically the` ContainerArguments', but what?